# Compliment or Removal of elements of text File 2 in another text File 1

Tags: python, unix, awk, sed, grep

Any help regarding the best approach for taking the difference of two files or in other words compliment of a file ? something in Unix or Shell scripting or some direct python utility?

Let's say: File 1 has below.

- A
- A
- A
- B
- B
- D
- E
- E
- F
- 15
- A

File 2 has below text:

- A
- B
- D
- E
- A

It is known that, File 2 is subset of File 1 and output should be: Removal of first occurrence of elements of File 2 from File 1. So the output looks like below:

- A
- A
- B
- E
- F
- 15

In other words, output is nothing but compliment of File 2 in File 1. (Ordering is not important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;n=NR;next}
    {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)if($0==a[i]){delete a[i];next}print}' file2 file1
```

will give you:

```
A
B
E
F
15
A
```

The codes are straightforward and telling what they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `python`,

```
file_1_data = open('file_1.txt').read().split('\n')   
file_2_data = open('file_2.txt').read().split('\n')

for data in file_2_data:
    if data in file_1_data:
        file_1_data.remove(data)

open('file_1.txt','w').write('\n'.join(file_1_data))
```

Comment: This approach does not take care of cases where elements are in duplicates in file 1 and it removes all the matching elements present in file 2 and hence, not the desired output which I have asked.

Comment: @Linguist It will not remove all the elements in the list, And you willget the desired output too. Please try it then you will get to know that.

Answer (score 0):

`comm` is best suited for this task, but needs sorted input

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
15
A
A
B
E
F
```

From `man comm`

```
   comm - compare two sorted files line by line

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

If output needs to be sorted as shown in expected output

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sort -n
A
A
B
E
F
15
```